# how to check multiple string value are empty or blank at one shot using java

Tags: java, string

I've scenario to validate given input param is empty or not, I've list of fields with datatype **string** and **date** - `productId,productName,productType,productRating,productSellDate and productReturnDate`

I want to check these input params are `null` or `empty` or `blank` for each field and if any one of the field is `empty` or `blank` or `null` - it should throw `NullPointerException` with field name.

Please find my code below - since I'm new to Java please apologize for the coding standard. I don't know how to get the field name which has `empty` or `null` when I throw `NullPointerException`

And I'm calling `validate` and `validateDate` for each string, is there any option to validate all these param in one go?

Please suggest if there is any better way of writing the below piece of code. Appreciated your help in advance! Thanks.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String productId = "";
        String productName = "Apple";
        String productType = "Electronics";
        String productRating = "Good";
        Date productSellDate = new Date();
        Date productReturnDate = new Date();

        System.out.println(validate(productId));
        System.out.println(validate(productName));
        System.out.println(validate(productType));
        System.out.println(validate(productRating));

        System.out.println(validateDate(productSellDate));
        System.out.println(validateDate(productReturnDate));

    }


    private static String validate(String s) {
        if (s.isBlank() || s.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException("input param is empty"); // how to get the string field name which is empty or null or blank
        } else {
            return "valid";
        }
    }


    private static String validateDate(Date d) {
        if (d == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("sell or return date is empty"); // how to get the date field name which is empty or null or blank
        } else {
            return "date is valid";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look to : https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Comment: You can use `ObjectUtils` from `org.apache.commons.lang3`

    ObjectUtils.allNotNull(productId, productName, productType, productRating, productSellDate, productReturnDate);

Comment: with javax-validation yes, but indirectly. You have to specify the message yourself exemple : `@NotNull(message = "propertyX is null")`

Comment: Try overloading method `validate` and add a second method parameter which is the name of the thing that you are validating, i.e. `validate(String name, String value)` and `validate(String name, Date value)`

Comment: @user16320675 yes sorry, ObjectUtils does not match your need, follow this tutorial  https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Comment: As an aside I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

You can write it like this to take any number of input and throw if any one fo them are null or blank or empty

```java
private static String validate(String... strings) {
    for (String s : strings) {
        if (s == null || s.isBlank() || s.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException("input param is empty");
        }
    }
    return "valid";
}
```

and you can call it with any number of inputs

```java
validate("1", "2", null, "");
```

Comment: Thank you @AmrDeveloper! How to get the field name when we throw NullPointerException?

Comment: You are welcome @DaveBrady you can get the value or the index of it by putting it on exception message but you can't get the variable name in the runtime

Comment: `String#isEmpty` is redundant and unnecessary after calling [`String#isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()).  `if ( Objects.isNull( s ) || s.isBlank() ) {…`

Comment: You are right @BasilBourque but i just converted his code to show him the idea

Comment: @BasilBourque and if the response is to throw a `NullPointerException` anyway, there is no need to do it manually: `if(s.isBlank()) throw new NullPointerException();` does the entire job.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider it just a minor improvement over the solution that you have got. It certainly isn’t a one-shot validation of all the variables. My idea is to do validation and assignment of each in the same line. For example:

```
    String productId = validate("", "productId");
    String productName = validate("Apple", "productName");
```

Result:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: productId

The message mentions that the `productId` is blank/empty.

This obviously requires `validate()` to return the validated object in the case where it doesn’t throw.

```
private static String validate(String s, String message) {
    if (s == null || s.isBlank()) {
        throw new NullPointerException(message);
    } else {
        return s;
    }
}
```

We don’t need `isEmpty()` as an explicit condition since `isBlank()` also returns true for the completely empty string. Whether you want to check for `null`, you know best yourself.

For non-String variables simply use the built-in `Objects.requireNonNull()`:

```
    LocalDate productSellDate = Objects.requireNonNull(
            LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()), "productSellDate");
    LocalDate productReturnDate = Objects.requireNonNull(
            LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()), "productReturnDate");
```

`LocalDate` is a class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API that I recommend for all of your date work. A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day. If you need the time too, find some other class from the same API.