# How to combine isEmpty, isBlank and null check while validating string in java

Tags: java, java-8

I'm validating given string is `null`, `isEmpty` or `isBlank` and I've use case where I've to check either `productId` or `productItem` should present or `productName` and `productPrice` should contains value. For that I've written below if condition but it looks very clumsy and not readable. Can someone please help me how can we simplify this if condition and write in more readable format.

```
public class validate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String productId = "";
        String productItem = "";
        String productName = "Apple";
        String productPrice = "1500";

        if ((!productId.isEmpty() && !productId.isBlank() && productId != null
                || !productItem.isEmpty() && !productItem.isBlank() && productItem != null)
                || (!productName.isEmpty() && !productName.isBlank() && productName != null
                && !productPrice.isEmpty() && !productPrice.isBlank() && productPrice != null)) {

            System.out.println("valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not valid");
        }

}
}
```

Comment: I've seen that before... continuation of [How to check two argument in java is either one of them null or both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69831227/16320675) or [how to check multiple string value are empty or blank at one shot using java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69827029/16320675) ?

Comment: There is no `isBlank()` in Java 8, so why do you tag your question with `java-8` but ask about a method introduced in Java 11? Besides, it should be obvious that an empty string is also a blank string, so if you test for `! isBlank()`, there is no need to test for `! isEmpty()`. Besides that, the reasonable solution is not to let the strings become `null` in the first place.

Comment: And stop asking the same question again.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can often simplify code by defining auxiliary methods.

Define this helper:

```
boolean isNullEmptyOrBlank(String s) {
    return s == null || s.isEmpty() || s.isBlank());
}
```

then

```
if (isNullEmptyOrBlank(productId) && isNullEmptyOrBlank(productItem) && isNullOrEmptyOrBlank(productName)) {
    // invalid - unknown product
}
else if (isNullOrEmptyOrBlank(productValue)) {
   // invalid - unknown price
}
else {
  // valid
}
```

I'm not sure if I got your intended logic correct, but you should get the idea.

In practice, I'd probably decide isNullEmptyOrBlank was a clunky name, and call it something like isSet instead.